# android how to set bootanimation interval help me please

Tags: android

I am changing my boot animation images but problem is repeating same images again & again  this is des0 file . This is my dess0 file. Please tell me the purpose of this file? How do I set my interval?? I containing my bootanimation.zip file have 2 things a folder which contain 40 pics and desc0.text file which contain this which is below. Please tell me how do I set my interval???

how do I set my boot animation interval

```
 1024 600 10
 p 0 0 part0
 p 1 0 part1
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of problems, first: according to your desc there should be three things in your zip namely, desct.txt, part0 and part1 folders. The numeric sequencing of files are very important. Also, the first loop is infinite so you'll get problems reaching part1.

I suggest follow the tutorial as explained in this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1096068).